# How to offer delivery option at time of shipping in Magento?

Tags: magento2, delivery, delivery-date

I am not too much technical person and running an eCommerce store for the fashion industry. I want to offer a custom delivery options to our customers. What is the way and how can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can not ask non-technical questions here, for that you can contact direct or can post in meta

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not technical, there are some extensions which may help you to offer custom delivery options.

**Paid extensions:**

- https://amasty.com/delivery-date-for-magento-2.html
- https://marketplace.magento.com/bsscommerce-order-delivery-date.html

**Free module:**

- https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date

If you have knowledge of creating a basic module in Magento 2, then you can try below tutorial:

- https://oyenetwork.com/articles/magento2-devliery-date-module-creation-from-scratch/

Please let me know if it helped.